# Android Studio SDK path contains accents

Tags: java, android, encoding

I have a probelm when I'm starting a new Android project. I proceed without a problem to the last step, but when I press finish, this error appears:

```
 Sync Android SDKs

 The path
 'C:\Users\Tom�\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk'
 does not refer to an Android SDK.

Android Studio will use its default SDK instead:
'C:\Users\Tomáš\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk'
 and will modify the project's local.properties file.
```

The problem is obviously caused by my user folder, which contains special characters ('á' and 'š'), because it's part of my name (I'm from the Czech Republic). Unfortunately, this folder cannot be renamed.

I have tried to change all the encodings setting to UTF-8, but it did not help at all.

I'll be grateful for every advice.

Comment: How are you "starting a new Android project"? This sounds like an internationalization bug that you should report (but who to report it to depends on what program is outputting this).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't help you with the localization problem, however I have had a similar issue and I hope that your problem can be resolved in a similar manor.

My advice would therefore be:

1. Create a new folder in your C:\ drive (name it something without special characters)
2. Copy and paste both your SDK and android studio to the new folder.
3. Enter the folder containing android studio and create a new shortcut to "studio64.exe" (for 64-bit. I think that is the right name, but I'm on my phone so I'm not sure)

---

I would also advice you to create another folder for your android studio projects by following step one above as the special characters may cause issues. (That was my original problem. Most things worked fine, but some were very strange indeed)